# Как объединить файл из двух других на лету?

Tags: windows, файлы, winapi, файловая-система

Нужно чтобы при открытии файла, например english.txt он собирался (создавался) из двух других файлов на лету.
Есть ли возможность реализовать такое, желательно в windows?
Интересуют любые варианты и идеи, как такое можно сделать.

Comment: Что такое **открытие файла**: операция чтения атрибутов файла, операция чтения данных файла, операция обращения к файлу через диалог открытия конкретным приложением или др. ? Что будет являться источников данных для записи в файл, при каких дополнительных условиях надо выполнить эту операцию и когда: перед открытием, после обращения к файлу и т.д.? Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, поточнее вопрос

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и замечания, не силен в данных терминологиях. Интересует операция чтения данных файла, источником файла могут быть другие файлы txt или иные варианты.
Операция чтения файла производится программой к коду которой нету доступа. Хотелось бы этой программе скормить нужный txt файл составленный из двух других файлов, фрагментов.